# How to set sort order while add attribute programmatically

Tags: attributes

I want to set sort order in attribute. In mysql file i m used this

```
  'sort_order' => 10
```

but it not worked

**[Edit]**

```
$installer->addAttribute('customer','badge', array( 
    'label'             => 'Badge',
    'type'              => 'text',    //backend_type
    'input'             => 'multiselect', //frontend_input
    'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',    
    'global'            =>  Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'source'            => 'marketplace/eav_entity_attribute_source_badge', // Goes to Step 2
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'default'           => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'unique'            => false,
    'note'              => '',
    'sort_order'        => 10

));
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'badge')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','checkout_onepage_register','checkout_onepage_register_guest','checkout_onepage_billing_address','adminhtml_customer','checkout_onepage_shipping_address','checkout_multishipping_register'))
    ->save();
```

Comment: we need a little bit more to work with to be able to help you. OF what entity/table you are trying to set this? Could you add the whole SQL query? WHAT doesn't work? What do you expect it to do? And what for/why?

Comment: I am add one attribute in customer attribute is created but in eav_entity_attribute table sort_order for this attribute is 0 but i want to change that so how to do that

Comment: Could you post the whole query that you have tried already?

Comment: 'sort_order' works fine for me at least in EE1.13.1.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `position` instead of sort_order.

```
'position' => 20
```

From `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup`

```
/**
 * Prepare customer attribute values to save in additional table
 *
 * @param array $attr
 * @return array
 */
protected function _prepareValues($attr)
{
    $data = parent::_prepareValues($attr);
    $data = array_merge($data, array(
        'is_visible'                => $this->_getValue($attr, 'visible', 1),
        'is_system'                 => $this->_getValue($attr, 'system', 1),
        'input_filter'              => $this->_getValue($attr, 'input_filter', null),
        'multiline_count'           => $this->_getValue($attr, 'multiline_count', 0),
        'validate_rules'            => $this->_getValue($attr, 'validate_rules', null),
        'data_model'                => $this->_getValue($attr, 'data', null),
        'sort_order'                => $this->_getValue($attr, 'position', 0)
    ));

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you add attribute programmatically that time you have to set order like this

```
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
->getAttribute('customer', 'badge')
->setSortOrder(100)
 ->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','checkout_onepage_register','checkout_onepage_register_guest','checkout_onepage_billing_address','adminhtml_customer','checkout_onepage_shipping_address','checkout_multishipping_register'))
->save();
```

'sort_order' is not worked

Comment: This is also worked

Answer (score 1):

The sort_order is the attribute that you need to change to move the attributes around the page. If the sort order is sequential then a simple trick to add some padding is to run the following command

```
UPDATE eav_entity_attribute SET sort_order = (sort_order*10) WHERE attribute_group_id = 4
```

Which will multiple each sort order by 10 allowing you to move the attributes around easier.

Comment: not worked. In that sort order is 0